# What is the best way to make sure I am not using any unavailable API's on OSX?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I am writing an OSX app in Xcode 6 but want my application to have support for OSX 10.7 and up. Unfortunately Xcode 6 only includes SDK for 10.10 and 10.9.

What is the best way to make sure I am not using any unavailable API's that would crash on 10.7 and 10.8?

Comment: It's a bit of a hack, but you can try [`MJGAvailability.h`](https://github.com/mattjgalloway/MJGFoundation/blob/master/Source/Utilities/MJGAvailability.h) from [https://github.com/mattjgalloway/MJGFoundation/](https://github.com/mattjgalloway/MJGFoundation/). I've also heard good things about [Deploymate](http://www.deploymateapp.com/), but have never tried it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the moment, there's no easy way to do this, since as you said, 10.9 is the farthest back you can specify. Until Xcode 7 is released, which I believe will only help with more recent SDKs anyway, you have few choices, none at all convenient:

1. Keep a cheap Mac around loaded with 10.7 and Xcode 4 or 5 (whichever comes with the 10.7 SDK) and try building your project there (so the compiler will automatically catch all unknown symbols). You can even get a capable Mini and keep it "headless" (no monitor/keyboard/pointing device) and use remote desktop to drive it. You can use a hosted repo or a shared drive to access your latest code for testing alongside your primary working Mac. This truly is the best catch-all, since you should have a way to reproduce problems that may occur only on the older OS version anyway.
2. Maintain a large enough partition on your existing Mac's internal (or an external) hard drive with 10.7/older Xcode into which you can periodically boot to do the same thing. This is less convenient than 1 for what I hope are obvious reasons, but workable if buying another Mac isn't a viable option.
3. The absolute worst and most error-prone way would be to go through all your code manually and look up their availability. This obviously sucks but you should already know your own app's design and whether or not you're "alright so far", so with this in mind, you can apply this basic check to any new code changes / planned features as you go.
4. **[Edit]** See JWWalker's comment below.

For an application I wrote and maintain for Uncle Sam (the current version of which must support back to 10.6), I use a mixture of 1 and 3. That is, I keep a headless Mini loaded with 10.6 and Xcode 3 but develop on the latest hardware / software. I vet any bug fixes or minor enhancements I have to make as reasonably as I can by stopping and thinking of my design / changes and verifying with the documentation that the symbol(s) involved are available. I've grown with the platform so I'm pretty good about avoiding newer API anyway but I occasionally get caught out when I go to build the internal beta for distribution (which must be done on the headless Mini so it can catch any final problems).

Another gotcha with supporting old stuff while using new stuff, however, is when editing NIBs/XIBs. Newer IB versions tend to auto-upgrade the format to be "helpful" (or they force it) if you use the newer tools, which mean they can't be read even to be compiled by `ibtool`. Fortunately these days, I'm just issuing bug fixes to code for the production version of this app since the focus of late is on the next major version, which mercifully may target 10.9 and up.

Again I'll say "this obviously sucks."

Comment: Although it's not officially supported, it might be worth a try to use an SDK from an older Xcode.  That is, get a copy of Xcode 4, dive into the app packages to find where each Xcode hides the SDKs, and copy or symlink the 10.7 SDK into Xcode 6.  I haven't done specifically that, but I've used the 10.6 SDK from Xcode 3 within Xcode 4.

Comment: True, I always forget about this approach. Mainly because of the hacky nature of it all (and that it's easily broken). :-) But good catch.

Comment: What if one were to say `#define MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_7` in a prefix or precompiled header, while using, say, the 10.9 SDK?

Comment: @JWWalker The SDK selected in your target build settings already defines this macro. You'll get a warning unless you #undef it first. Then ... nothing happens because the target build settings override this.

Comment: I don't think you're right about target build settings overriding it.  I tried `#define MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED 1070` at the top of a prefix while using the 10.8 SDK, and as far as I could tell, `MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED` was actually defined to be 1070 in compiled sources.  The header AvailabilityMacros.h will define `MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED` to be the SDK version **if** it is not already defined.

Comment: Yet when I redefined it to 10.5 in a project that uses 10.9 features nothing was flagged.

Comment: Did you define `MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED` to 1050? If you define it to `MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_5` before that macro has been defined (as one of my previous comments may have misled you into doing), then it's not doing what you think. (In my 10.8 SDK test case, I tried using the `allowsMagnification` property of `NSScrollView`, which is new in 10.8, and it did get flagged.) The other thing to watch out for is that you can't define `MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED` to be less than your deployment version.

Comment: Hmm. I think you're right. Don't have time to test thoroughly today but it looks like another possible alternative, though the tech note about it says it's not considered best practice any more.